# Dependency Parsing graph for a paragraph

Tags: nlp, dependency-parsing, stanford-parser

I am working on a NLP project. I want to create a dependency parsing graph for an entire paragraph, instead of sentence. Is there an existing method for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such dependency parsing for a paragraph but you can use Stanford coreference resolution on the sentences and extract particular dependencies.